# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ensuretemp'

Tags: python, python-3.4, pytest

Following the example at http://py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/path.html#basic-interactive-example

```
import py
temppath = py.test.ensuretemp('py.path_documentation')
```

Raises the error
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ensuretemp'

Python version 3.4.3, `py` version 1.4.26.

```
In [1]: import py

In [2]: dir(py.test)
Out[2]:
['Class',
 'Collector',
 'File',
 'Function',
 'Generator',
 'Instance',
 'Item',
 'Module',
 'Session',
 'UsageError',
 '__all__',
 '__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__spec__',
 '__version__',
 '_fillfuncargs',
 '_preloadplugins',
 'cmdline',
 'collect',
 'deprecated_call',
 'exit',
 'fail',
 'fixture',
 'freeze_includes',
 'importorskip',
 'main',
 'mark',
 'raises',
 'set_trace',
 'skip',
 'xfail',
 'yield_fixture']


In [4]: py.test.__file__
Out[4]: '/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/snap/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pytest.py'
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's likely that you need to `import py.test` to get the attribute `ensuretemp`.

Comment: What do you get from running `dir(py.test)`, and `py.fest.__file__`?

Comment: @polarise import py.test, py.test.ensuretemp('py.path_documentation') raises the same error

Comment: what do you get when you run `py.test`?

Comment: @user3012759 when I run py.test from my project root, it loads my tests and my tests pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you're doing everything correctly as documentation shows. I'm unable to get it working either. On other hand, pytest has fixture `tmpdir`, which does what you need in the test: gives you unique temporary directory for your test.

Here is an example of test:

```
def test_one(tmpdir):
    test_file = tmpdir.join('dir', 'file').ensure(file=True)
    test_file.write('test\ntest\n')

    assert test_file.read().rsplit() == ['test', 'test']
```

On other hand, pytest uses py.path, which has py.path.local object, and with use of `tempfile.mkdtemp` you can create temporary dir object:

```
import tempfile

tempdir = py.path.local(tempfile.mkdtemp())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `mkdtemp` directly from `py.path`

```
In [127]: import py.path    
In [128]: py.path.local.mkdtemp()
Out[128]: local('/tmp/tmpP1835f')
```